# Any Good Equation Editors that offer copy-paste image support?

Tags: math-software

So I'm currently studying at University and have been looking for a decent program that is capable of writing equations quickly with shortcuts, LaTex, etc... However, I want to be able to instantly just copy it from the editor, and paste it into Evernote as an image so that I can keep it organised with my Lecture Notes.

So far I've tried a variety of different ones that I can find via Google, but they are all lacking or over complicated.

I originally used the MathiVersity Editor since it has the copy-paste image functionality but it lacks speed due to no shortcuts for common things like; Fractions, Matrices, Functions, etc...

I'm all for learning LaTeX as well as long as it has the same functionality described above. For example;

- Write LaTeX code.
- Select Code and Copy.
- Paste into Evernote as an image and code is formatted as actual symbols, etc...

Anything anyone can recommend would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you ask over at [tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com), it's possible they could help you configure your LaTeX file so that it renders exactly the way you want automatically (i.e. only the equation and not a full page of padding, titles and such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a cheap LaTeX solution, you can use any LaTeX renderer such as this very Mathematics page, and screen copy to an image editor for cropping.

Example:

As a formula

$\ \ \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\aleph_0!\iff\dfrac{\land}{\lor}$

As an inserted picture

[image]

---

For a more interactive (menu driven) solution, MS Word has a quite decent equation editor.

[image]

Interestingly, it can be coupled to MS Mathematics, a not-so-elementary symbolic computation utility, and supports MathML markup.

---

For the best graphical quality, you may consider zooming-in on the page via your browser before taking the screen copy, and later scale down before or after pasting.

Comment: This is what I do when I need equations as images.